# How to extract Clojure REPL history

Tags: clojure, read-eval-print-loop

I have written some code within the plain console REPL of Clojure (`lein repl`). Now I would like to extract the history in order to get the code that I have written in there. Can I do this somehow?

Comment: I take it a simple copy paste doesn't do it? You can use the up and down arrows to retrieve past/future commands. A good practice: try to eval code from a file buffer to the REPL and use the REPL only to test the code or make slight changes.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Each Leiningen project stores its REPL usage history in the `.lein-repl-history` file. There's a global `repl-history` file as well, located at `~/.lein`.